# Adding ocean_basemap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps

Has anyone added the [Ocean](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer) Base map to QGIS?

I was able to add the OpenLayers plugin and get the "land" basemap (among others), but not the ocean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the REST service to gdal service description file then you can add this layer to QGIS.

For more details click [here](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Arcgis_rest)

Please check the screenshot [image: screenshot].

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still new to QGIS, but this has been very helpful.

Comment: Please summarize the main concept here, otherwise this answer might turn useless when the links break.

Comment: It has come to pass :(