# Locating WMS on Esri basemap?

Tags: wms, arcgis-online-basemaps

I need to locate the WMS (not WMTS) for the following ESRI Ocean Basemap for use in a WMS only application:

http://goto.arcgisonline.com/maps/Ocean_Basemap

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the [WMTS endpoint](http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) is exposed on this service and WMS is unavailable.

Related question: [Adding ocean_basemap in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/how-to-add-ocean-basemap-in-qgis)