# Printable Basemap in QGIS Web Client?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-web-client

Currently running Version 2.14.13

I'm having trouble getting base maps to appear when I go to print a map in QGIS Cloud. I've been using Google Hybrid from the OpenLayers plugin, and while it appears when I pull up my web map, it disappears when I attempt to use the print feature. I realized OpenLayers is outdated so I tried to use the QuickMapServices plugin instead.

I've tried using OSM Standard from the QuickMapServices plugin. However, when I go to publish my map in QGIS, I get an error message stating "Unsupported Layers Found" in reference to the OSM Standard layer. I know there is a way to add a service within the QuickMap setting, but this is a process that I'm not familiar with, nor do I know if this is something that will even make a difference here.
I realize I could just upload some aerial photos, but the size of those files doesn't really make it feasible with the amount of DB storage I have left. Any ideas of a solution?

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that printing Google layers isn't allowed under the license agreement. It has always been that Google layers appear on the canvas but disappear in the print dialog. Do other open data layers also vanish during print?

Comment: It appears that in fact other open data layers will appear during print. This is not entirely what I'm looking for, as it would be nice to have the capability of printing a satellite image, but this is enough for now to answer my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Google layers can't be printed or exported as a PDF etc. I cannot find a reference straight away but I am fairly sure this is due to the license agreement by Google. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118177/problem-with-print-composer-when-exporting-a-map-with-google-maps-plugin-in-the) is a similar question.

Other open data layers can be printed however, Bing should be printable but you could also try Esri basemap layers, see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/adding-ocean-basemap-in-qgis) for ocean layers and a quick [how-to for Esri world imagery](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/adding-esris-online-world-imagery-dataset-to-qgis/).